backspace and formatting in form input
Im working on a school project, creating a "webshop" (its just for practice - not real).
Im trying to format the input for the users card number so that it looks like:
1234 5678 9101 1112.
when typing the cardnumber formatting works, but when the user starts backspacing, problems arise.
All is fine when backspacing through the string - i've created a function that skips the spaces, and made sure that the user cannot interact with them, but when we reach the first 4 digits (1234) backspace deletes two characters at a time instead of one, and i cannot figure out why.
heres my code for handling backspace and formatting in the cardNumber input field:
//handle formatting for the cardnumber
formatCardNumber(value) {
        let formattedValue = value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // Remove all non-digit characters
        // Insert a space after every 4 digits
        if (formattedValue.length <= 16) {
            formattedValue = formattedValue.replace(/(\d{4})(?=\d)/g, '$1 ');
        } else {
            formattedValue = formattedValue.substring(0, 16); // Limit to 16 digits
            formattedValue = formattedValue.replace(/(\d{4})(?=\d)/g, '$1 '); // Add spaces
        }
        return formattedValue; // Return the formatted value
    },

    // Handle backspace behavior specifically for card number inputs
    handleCardNumberBackspace(cardNumberInput, e) {
        if (e.key === 'Backspace') { // Check if the Backspace key is pressed
            let value = cardNumberInput.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // Remove spaces and non-digits
            let cursorPos = cardNumberInput.selectionStart; // Get the current cursor position

            if (cursorPos > 0 && cardNumberInput.value[cursorPos - 1] === ' ') { 
                // If the cursor is before a space, remove the preceding digit and the space
                cardNumberInput.value = value.substring(0, cursorPos - 1) + value.substring(cursorPos);
                cardNumberInput.setSelectionRange(cursorPos - 1, cursorPos - 1); // Update cursor position
            } else {
                // Remove the digit at the cursor position
                cardNumberInput.value = value.substring(0, cursorPos - 1) + value.substring(cursorPos);
                cardNumberInput.setSelectionRange(cursorPos - 1, cursorPos - 1); // Update cursor position
            }

            cardNumberInput.value = this.formatCardNumber(cardNumberInput.value); // Reapply formatting
        }
    },


This question is similar to: Format credit card number. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try this code. May solve your problem.


function formatInput(el){
let cardEntered=el.value.replaceAll(" ","");
let outTXT="";
for(let a=0;a<cardEntered.length;a+=4){
outTXT+=cardEntered.substr(a, 4)+" ";
}
el.value=outTXT.trim();
}

function getText(formatedTXT){
return formatedTXT.replaceAll(" ","");
}
<input type="text" onclick="alert(getText(this.value));" oninput="formatInput(this);" value="1234 5678 abcd"/>



